# Cycle plus triangles graph of even order

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity, connectedness, coloring, matching-theory

A cycle plus triangles graph is a 4-regular graph $G$ with a Hamiltonian circuit $C$ and such that the chords of $C$ induce a set of disjoint triangles (3-circuits). Our interest is in these graphs when they have an even number of triangles, so that the order of the graph is even.  The chromatic index of these graphs is not always 4 (that is, they can't always be edge-colored with 4 colors).  In the picture you see an example of a cycle plus triangles with an even number of triangles and chromatic index 5, so it is a class 2 graph.

[image: example]

The graph in the picture has an edge 2-cut (that is, two edges that if deleted make the graph fall apart).  Our main question is the following:

> **Question 1** Is it possible to produce an example of a cycle plus triangles graph of even order which is class 2 and 3-connected, that is, so that it has no edge 2-cuts?

We have a side question (which might better belong to the cs sister site, but still)

> **Question 2** What is the complexity of deciding whether a cycle plus triangles graph of even order is class 1 or class 2?

Comment: The main result of [this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3797/6a5edbc1002551ee23576186115c2faab7e0.pdf) implies that any 4-regular, 3-edge-connected graph of even order is matching covered, which is some of the way to showing that such graphs are class 1.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thank you for the paper, I will read it ...

Comment: I was wrong about that being the main result of the paper, it (Theorem 1.1 in the paper) is a tool they use. They are simply citing somewhere in [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=bmHaBwAAQBAJ&lpg=PR9&ots=ult59xRFR-&dq=wallis%20One%20Factorizations.&lr&pg=PR9#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thank you, then I will study this then ...

Comment: @MishaLavrov Right, after the correction it became class 1 ...

Comment: @MishaLavrov The example I was thinking of has an odd number of vertices ...